# CSS3 transition on iOS devices (iPhone / iPad): applying opacity transition the DOM object flashy

Tags: ios, ipad, css, css-transitions, mobile-webkit

I have a simple IMG inside of a DIV.
With JavaScript, I apply a transition to DIV element:

```
<div style="transition: opacity 0.8s linear; opacity: 0.5;"><img
  src="..." /></div>
```

When the end of transition time, che DIV element (or maybe the parent of DIV) go invisible and return visible in one instant.
This issue make a bat flash.

I look this only on my iPAD. With my PC the transition is perfect.

How can I remove this problem?

Comment: I discovered that the defect is much less frequent if there are not AJAX commands in progress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hardware accelerate the div. To do so you need to add the following style:

```
 -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

They say the following styles could also help to enable hardware acceleration but it didnt work for me.

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

To help debug it thru you will need to run Safari on Mac from the terminal with the following keys:

```
$> export CA_COLOR_OPAQUE=1 
$> /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari
```

CA_COLOR_OPAQUE shows which elements are  accelerated.